# Which one of "Crows", "Crows Zero" and "Worst" takes place first?

Tags: crows, worst

I only watched *Crows Zero* and *Crows Zero 2* (both are live-action) and I found there are the related manga *Crows* and *Worst*.

I want to know which of these manga takes place first, and what the chronological order of these three is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as story progression goes (in chronological order), it is *Crows Zero*, *Crows*, *Worst*.

However, *Crows* was the first series that was published (1990-1998) and then *Worst* was the second to be published (2001-2013). *Crows Zero* began after *Worst* (2008-).

There are also other manga series too:

- *Crows Gaiden* (1995-1998)
- *Sono Go no Crows* (2001)
- *Crows Zero 2* (2012-)

Each different series follows a different set of characters.

Keep in mind that *Crows* and *Worst* are the main stories. The other series are all series based on the side characters of the main story.

Answer (score -1):

The chronological order would be:

- *Crows Zero*
- *Crows Zero 2*
- *Crows* (manga)
- *Crows Gaiden*

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. How about *Worst*? And could you explain a little bit why *Gaiden* follows *Crows* chronologically?